# Boost Optional with Boost Thread compilation issue

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread, boost-optional

My environment is Visual Stuido 2013, VC12, Boost 1.59. 
The following code (a minimal repro of the real code):

```
#include "boost/thread.hpp"
#include "boost/optional.hpp"

class MyClass
{
public:

    template <typename T>
    operator const T& () const;

};

boost::optional<MyClass> foo()
{
    boost::optional<MyClass> res;
    return res;
}

int main(int argc)
{
    foo();
}
```

Doesn't compile, the error:

```
    1>------ Build started: Project: TestBoostOptional, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
    1>  main.cpp
    1>c:\workspace\third_party\boost_1_59_0\boost/optional/optional.hpp(297): error C2664: 'void boost::optional_detail::optional_base::construct(MyClass &&)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'boost::detail::thread_move_t' to 'const MyClass &'
    1>          with
    1>          [
    1>              T=MyClass
    1>          ]
    1>          Reason: cannot convert from 'boost::detail::thread_move_t' to 'const MyClass'
    1>          with
    1>          [
    1>              T=MyClass
    1>          ]
    1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
    1>          c:\workspace\third_party\boost_1_59_0\boost/optional/optional.hpp(292) : while compiling class template member function 'boost::optional_detail::optional_base::optional_base(boost::optional_detail::optional_base &&)'
    1>          with
    1>          [
    1>              T=MyClass
    1>          ]
    1>          c:\workspace\third_party\boost_1_59_0\boost/optional/optional.hpp(873) : see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::optional_detail::optional_base::optional_base(boost::optional_detail::optional_base &&)' being compiled
    1>          with
    1>          [
    1>              T=MyClass
    1>          ]
    1>          c:\workspace\third_party\boost_1_59_0\boost/optional/optional.hpp(766) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::optional_detail::optional_base' being compiled
    1>          with
    1>          [
    1>              T=MyClass
    1>          ]
    1>          main.cpp(14) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::optional' being compiled
```

Note the `#include "boost/thread.hpp"`. When removing this include the code compiles. Anything that can be done to workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must define `BOOST_THREAD_USES_MOVE` before you use any boost header.

```
#define BOOST_THREAD_USES_MOVE
```

More information are located [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/emulations.html#thread.emulations.move). This define emulates a move by `Boost.Move` which is necessary here.

> In order to implement Movable classes, move parameters and return
>   types Boost.Thread uses the rvalue reference when the compiler support
>   it. On compilers not supporting it Boost.Thread uses either the
>   emulation provided by Boost.Move or the emulation provided by the
>   previous versions of Boost.Thread depending whether
>   BOOST_THREAD_USES_MOVE is defined or not. This macros is unset by
>   default when BOOST_THREAD_VERSION is 2. Since BOOST_THREAD_VERSION 3,
>   BOOST_THREAD_USES_MOVE is defined.

Also see [Boost.Move](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/thread/build.html):

> Boost.Thread uses by default an internal move semantic implementation.
>   Since version 3.0.0 you can use the move emulation emulation provided
>   by Boost.Move.
>
> When BOOST_THREAD_VERSION==2 define BOOST_THREAD_USES_MOVE if you want
>   to use Boost.Move interface. When BOOST_THREAD_VERSION==3 define
>   BOOST_THREAD_DONT_USE_MOVE if you don't want to use Boost.Move
>   interface.

Comment: Impressive answer. Something I didn't know. And with helpful documentation quotes and links. What else could we ask for :)

Comment: Accepting this, another option is to `#define BOOST_THREAD_VERSION 3`. However this doesn't explain why this happens.